# jQuery hide() not working (IE9)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, hide

I am making a div which should be hidden when the page loads, then visible once the user clicks a link. The code below works in FF / IE7 / IE8 but not in IE9, where the div is visible at all times ( without content ). Thanks in advance!

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#translateBoxen').hide();
      $('#translateToggle').click(function() {
         $('#translateBoxen').toggle(400);
         return false;
      });
  });
</script> // This is the jQuery code to hide and toggle the div //

<div style="width:200px;height:100px;position:absolute;"> // Just a holder that's needed for the site
  <a class="vitxtext" style="font-size:10px;" id="translateToggle" href="#">
      Translate
  </a>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <div id="translateBoxen">
       // BOX CONTENT //
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser's error console (F12 in IE9). It most probably will be because of an error in some line of code that occurs before the hide() call. Secondly, if you plan on hiding it on dom ready, you might as well set is display property to none in your CSS to avoid any jumpiness while loading.

Comment: if i set display to none, will the div still pop up when i use the toggle command via jQuery? The code is working now btw, i was using an IE9 emulator hehe but it worked in the real IE9

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CEGCs/ this works on IE9.

Comment: Yes, it will still popup when you toggle() via jQuery even if you set it to display:none from your CSS.

Comment: Check if your document is in quirk mode.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you hide the `<div>` with CSS? Just set to to `display:none` in your CSS, then when the toggle link is clicked for the first time it should be shown.

There is no reason why `toggle()` should not work in IE9, are you getting any script errors?

Comment: Are you using jQuery 2+ ?

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but try making a `.hidden` class with `display:none`, then hiding/showing by putting `addClass('hidden')` and `removeClass('hidden')` instead of show/hide.